# How do you force Random Number Generation for each element in an array in Swift 3.0?

Tags: random, swift3, arc4random

I am having a strange problem in Swift 3.0 generating random numbers [in this case CGPoints]. I am trying to build a very simple particle filter and I am having trouble initially randomizing alll the particles using the code below.

When I iterate through my set of 'particles' a unique random point is generated [GOOD] but each particle gets the exact same unique random point [BAD].  I am not sure what I am doing wrong to ensure that each particle gets a unique random point

Anyone have any suggestions how I can force each particle to get a unique random point?

Thanks

Stan

Problem Function.

```
func randomize(
    theListOfParticles: [RegionParticle]
    ) -> [RegionParticle] {

    var returnListOfParticles = [SRLSystemRegionParticle]()

    for particle in theListOfParticles {
        particle.position = self.randomPointInRegion()
        returnListOfParticles.append( particle )

    }
    return returnListOfParticles
}
```

Helper Function

```
/**
Get a random point in the region.
- Returns: CGPoint
*/
func randomPointInRegion() -> CGPoint {
    let x : CGFloat = Math.randomCGFloat(
        min: -(self.rect?.size.width)!,
        max: (self.rect?.size.width)!
    )
    let y : CGFloat = Math.randomCGFloat(
        min: -(self.rect?.size.width)!,
        max: (self.rect?.size.width)!
    )

    let returnCGPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint(
        x: x,
        y: y
    )
    return returnCGPoint
}
```

The random gen function [in a separate class of all my math functions.]

```
/**
Generate a random CGFloat.
- Parameters:
- min: CGFloat
- max: CGFloat
- Returns: a CGFloat
*/
static func randomCGFloat( min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) * (max - min) + min
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I figured out what was going on.

When I created the initial array of Particles I used the following.

```
    let newListOfParticles = Array(
        repeatElement(
            defaultParticle,
            count: self.numberOfParticles
        )
    )
```

I thought that function would make a unique copy of the defaultParticles for each index.  I was mistaken.

Instead, the function just created references pointing back to the initial one.  So the randomizing loops was just operating on the same particle over and over again.

I changed the list initialization to the following:

```
    for _ in 1...self.numberOfParticles {

        newListOfParticles.append( RegionParticle( withRegion: self ) )

    }
```

So each entry is truly unique now, and that seemed to fix the problem.

So I was only partially crazy.